# Setup tailwind css with Nx microfront-ends using angular and buildable library

Tags: angular, tailwind-css, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I am trying to setup tailwind css with nx mono-repo using Angular, following the steps from here https://nx.dev/recipes/other/using-tailwind-css-with-angular-projects#tailwind-css-setup-scenarios

1. **Create Nx Workspace**

   npx create-nx-workspace@latest fetebird-ui

   cd fetebird-ui
2. **Install nrwl/angular package**

   npm install @nrwl/angular
3. **Create multiple application**

   nx g @nx/angular:host host --remotes=product,discount,order
4. Create a Buildable library

   npx nx g @nx/angular:lib my-lib --buildable --add-tailwind
5. Add Tailwind CSS to an existing Angular application

   npx nx g @nx/angular:setup-tailwind host

   npx nx g @nx/angular:setup-tailwind project

**apps/product/tailwind.config.ts**

```
const { createGlobPatternsForDependencies } = require('@nx/angular/tailwind');
const { join } = require('path');
const sharedTailwindConfig = require('../../libs/tailwind-preset/tailwind.config');

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  presets: [sharedTailwindConfig],
  content: [
    join(__dirname, 'src/**/!(*.stories|*.spec).{ts,html}'),
    ...createGlobPatternsForDependencies(__dirname),
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

**libs/service/tailwind.config.ts**

```
const { createGlobPatternsForDependencies } = require('@nx/angular/tailwind');
const { join } = require('path');
const sharedTailwindConfig = require('../../libs/tailwind-preset/tailwind.config');


/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  presets: [sharedTailwindConfig],
  content: [
    join(__dirname, 'src/**/!(*.stories|*.spec).{ts,html}'),
    ...createGlobPatternsForDependencies(__dirname),
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

**Create tailwind-preset**

```
module.exports = {
 presets: [
    require('./tailwind-preset.js')
 ],
  theme: {
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

**project.json**

```
{
  "projectType": "library",
  "root": "libs/tailwind-preset",
  "sourceRoot": "libs/tailwind-preset",
  "targets": {},
  "tags": []
}
```

**tailwind-preset.js**

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
  },
  plugins: [
    ],
}
```

**apps/host/style.scss**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**apps/product/style.scss**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

When we server multiple application, the tailwind css is not working.

```
nx serve host --open --devRemotes=product,discount,order
```

I just want to share the default tailwind css across all the application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nx Core Team member here

TailwindCSS runs a purge on the classes that are used within an Application.

Your Host Application is not linked to your remote Applications in any meaningful way, meaning Tailwind doesn't know about the classes that are used in your remote applications' code.

Because of this, it can strip them out of the final CSS bundle.

The easiest solution is to add an `implicitDependency` between your Host application and your Remote applications:

https://nx.dev/reference/project-configuration#implicitdependencies

Another solution is to add the paths to your remote applications in your host's `tailwind.config.js` file:

```js
content: [
    join(__dirname, 'src/**/!(*.stories|*.spec).{ts,html}'),
    ...createGlobPatternsForDependencies(__dirname),
    ...createGlobPatternsForDependencies(join(__dirname, relativePathToRemoteApplication))
  ],
```

Comment: Adding the relative path of second solution didn't work for me, However adding implicitDependency works for me

Answer (score 1):

I have written a blog post about how you can use Tailwind with microfrontends. Key is that your microfrontends have independence and that the shell does not have to be redeployed when you update the styles of a microfrontend.

You can achieve this by using a proxy component that is doing the Tailwind imports and has no view encapsulation such that it affects the whole MFE. The downside obviously is that you have more css because of redundant tailwind styles but it works fine and most business apps that build upon MFEs don't care about a bit more css.

https://ng-journal.com/blog/2022-12-02-tailwind-and-module-federation/

Answer (score 0):

@Colum Ferry `createGlobPatternsForDependencies` is not working, so @San Jaisy to use `tailwind.config.js` as a solution instead of `...createGlobPatternsForDependencies(join(__dirname, relativePathToRemoteApplication))` you need to pass `join(__dirname, relativePathToRemoteApplication)`